# How do i remove objects within another object's collection?

Tags: scene, collections, outliner

I have no idea how to phrase this properly, so I hope a gif will be able to show. This is a more a matter of scene collection organization rather than modelling, but its driving me nuts.

[image]

As shown, i'm trying to remove the objects within the "connector" object collection into the "Scene" collection but it just goes back into the connector object again.

My questions are:

1. Why is the "connector" object a collection in the first place?
2. Why are the 4 objects highlighted stuck within the "connector" object collection? (I'm not sure what i did to get them stuck there)
3. How do i go about removing these 4 objects from the "connector" collection into another collection, like the other objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'connector' object is not actually a collection. Most probably, the other four objects are parented to the connector object, thus causing them to be shown under this object in the Outliner.

In response to your second question, the objects *are* actually getting moved to the Scene Collection, but they remain where they are greyed out simply to display the hierarchy (as they are still parented to the 'connector' object). Scrolling down to the bottom of the Outliner should find the four objects in the Scene  Collection.

An alternative way to move these objects is to press M.